# Use Jquery on Facebook with ios wkwebview?

Tags: jquery, ios, code-injection, wkwebview

I'm looking for any way this can be done. I tried with the uiwebview using stackoverflow answers but nothing worked. I need to use jquery on Facebook in particular in a wkwebview. It doesn't matter to me if swift or objective c is used. All I want to do at first is change the background color. Thanks ahead of time for any help!

I tried to use jquery with evaluate javascript, in a wkwebview. Only the plain javascript I tried changed the background color, not jquery.

```
     func webView(_ webview: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {


    webView.evaluateJavaScript("var jq = document.createElement('script');
        jq.src = '//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);", completionHandler: nil)

    webView.evaluateJavaScript("$(document).ready(function(){$('body').css('background-color','blue');});", completionHandler: nil)

    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.style.background = 'red';", completionHandler: nil)

    }
```

Comment: Adding your trial code may help.

Comment: i added what i tried in the wkwebview